# functional programming: recursive loop output fibonacci sequence in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, fibonacci

Learning functional programming using scala. Came across this exercise.

Write a recursive function to get the nth Fibonacci number (http://mng.bz/C29s). The first two Fibonacci numbers are 0 and 1. The nth number is always the sum of the previous two—the sequence begins 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5. Your definition should use a local tail-recursive function.

```
def fib(n: Int): Int
```

My answer computes n+1 values and returns the nth. Can anyone show me a better implementation where the extra n+1th value is not computed?

```
object patterns {

    def fib(n : Int): Int = {
        @annotation.tailrec
        def go(n: Int, prev2: Int, prev: Int): Int =
            if(n<=0) prev2 
            else go(n-1, prev, prev2+prev)
        go(n, 0, 1)
      }
}
```

In case anyone is interested, this is from the book functional programming in scala by Chiusano and Bjarnason. Exercise 2.1
Looking forward to the replies.

Comment: If n==0, you must compute one value. How do you propose to lower that figure?

Answer (score 2):

I think this:

```
def fib2(n: Int): Int = {
  if (n < 1) 0
  else if (n < 2) 1
  else {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(i: Int, prev2: Int, prev: Int): Int =
      if (i == n) prev
      else go(i + 1, prev, prev2 + prev)
    go(2, 1, 1)
  }
}
```

or using ByName param:

```
def fib3(n: Int): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(n: Int, prev2: Int, prev: => Int): Int =
    //                            ^ ByName
    if (n <= 0) prev2
    else {
      val p = prev
      go(n - 1, p, prev2 + p)
    }
  go(n, 0, 1)
}
```

Comment: I had no idea about ByName param. Is there any performance advantage/disadvantage of using ByName param?

Comment: There is no performance advantage in this case. In this case compiler creates function wrapper for `prev2 + prev` and calls it only when ByName param `prev` is used in `else` branch.

Comment: By the way there is a mistake here `else go(n - 1, prev, prev2 + prev)` - `prev` wrapper will be called twice every time. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `stream` to implement it. Because the code is shorter and easier to understand.

```
      def fibo():Stream[Int] = {
        def addRec(o1:Int,o2:Int):Stream[Int] = {
          o1 #:: addRec(o2,o1 + o2)
        }
        addRec(1,1)
      }

      println(fibo().take(100).toList)
```

get the `nth` is simple to call `fibo.drop(n-1)(0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib2(n:Int):Int={
    if (n<1) 0
    else if (n<=2) 1
    else fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)
  }

  println(fib2(8))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**